# Can I use Smarty in Scheduled reminders?

Tags: smarty

Title says it all, I need to format some tokens and Smarty doesn't seem to work.

Is it possible to use smarty for Scheduled reminders?

Comment: I can never remember what works where but do you have CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY turned on in civicrm.settings.php?

Comment: yes it's on. we're using it elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is also a setting in "CiviMail Component Settings", not sure how long it's been there.

"Use Smarty in scheduled reminders" must be checked on.

Comment: 'twas added in 5.60

Comment: okay! good news, I've missed this point in the changelog :-)

Answer (score 2):

As said by Demerit, You can use smarty logics in Scheduled reminders also, but you need to set CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY to 1 in civicrm.settings.php

```
define( 'CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY', 1 );
```

Comment: if you're sure it works also for scheduled reminders, then I need to check our syntax! thanks.

Comment: Despite having this setting on in the settings file, Smarty is not working for us in scheduled reminders (tested it for event reminders only, though not sure it matters).

Comment: Confirm it does not work on activity reminders either. The email simply does not go out.

Comment: may be your editor is converting smarty code